Argo workflow API injection issue
I have a workflowtemplate that I have deployed to my k8 cluster, which I want to trigger from the argos API (I am using python but shouldnt matter). In addition to triggering it, I want to inject a variable into it when it runs.
I am able to trigger it, however, for the life of me I cant get it to accept the variable I try to inject
the workflow template is below
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: hello-world-template
  namespace: growth-signals
spec:
  entrypoint: hello-world
  templates:
    - name: hello-world
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: my_env_var
      container:
        image: alpine:latest
        command: [sh, -c]
        args: ["echo $MY_ENV_VAR"]
        env:
          - name: MY_ENV_VAR
            value: "{{inputs.parameters.my_env_var}}"

The payload (I am using requests) is below
data = {
    "resourceKind": "WorkflowTemplate",
    "resourceName": "hello-world-template",
    "workflowSpec": {
        "arguments": {
            "parameters": [
                {"name": "my_env_var", "value": "Hello World"}
            ]
        }
    }
}

I cant for the life of me get it to accept it I keep getting the error "templates.hello-world inputs.parameters.my_env_var was not supplied".
I have tried to change the payload to be workflowspec, arguments, or parameters (i.e. removing the parent key), but nothing matters at all.
As I said no issue connecting to the API, and launching the workflow, but I cant inject variables before it runs.
Any help would be massively appreciated as I have been stuck on this for quite a while now...

I believe the issue is that your WorkflowTemplate does not define any input parameters, you just have them defined for the template item.
Maybe try something similar to the following:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: hello-world-template
  namespace: growth-signals
spec:
  entrypoint: hello-world
  arguments: # NEW
    parameters:
      - name: my_env_var
  templates:
    - name: hello-world
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: my_env_var
      container:
        image: alpine:latest
        command: [sh, -c]
        args: ["echo $MY_ENV_VAR"]
        env:
          - name: MY_ENV_VAR
            value: "{{inputs.parameters.my_env_var}}"

